# How convert output tensor to one-hot tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to calculate loss from the softmax output vs target.
My target is like [0,0,1] and output is [0.3,0.3,0.4]
For the purpose, prediction is correct. But a cost function of below type doesn't account for this kind of accuracy

```
self._output = output = tf.nn.softmax(y)
self._cost = cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square( output - tf.reshape(self._targets, [-1])))
```

How can I easily convert the output [0.3,0.3,0.4] to [0,0,1] in TF itself?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The typical loss function used for comparing two probability distributions is called [cross entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy). TensorFlow has the [tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/nn.html#softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) function which implements that loss. In your case, you can simply do :

```
self._cost = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
                 y, tf.reshape(self._targets, [-1]))
```

But if you really want to convert `[0.3, 0.3, 0.4]` to a one-hot representation for a different purpose, you can use the [`tf.one_hot`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#one_hot) function as follows :

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
a = tf.constant([0.3, 0.3, 0.4])
one_hot_a = tf.one_hot(tf.nn.top_k(a).indices, tf.shape(a)[0])
print(one_hot_a.eval())
# prints [[ 0.  0.  1.]]
```